# how do I change string in all sub directories with same file name (For eg: data.txt) in linux using termianl?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
find . -name "data.txt" -print0 | grep -rl "pa028" ./ |xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/pa028/pa014/g'
```

I tried to replace pa028 with pa014 in the file name "data.txt" in all subdirectories. Can you find please correct me?

Comment: I did not understand your correction

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `grep` between `find -print0` and `xargs -0` because `grep` operates on lines, and this pipeline contains null-separated text instead of lines.  Additionally, `grep -r .` will ignore the standard input you so expensively set up `find` to produce.

```
find . -name "data.txt" -exec grep -q "pa028" {} \; -print0 |
xargs -r -0 sed -i '' -e 's/pa028/pa014/g'
```

The logic here is to use `-exec grep -q` as a predicate to `find` so we produce a null-terminated list of matching files (for which the `-exec` returns true) to pass to `xargs -r -0`.  (The `-r` option is important, too; you get weird errors if `xargs` runs anyway even though `find` produced no output.)

There is an extension to GNU `grep` to operate on null-terminated strings with `-z` and print null-terminated file names with `-Z -l` but that's a fairly recent development, so I'm not yet prepared to recommend that.

Comment: Rather than comment, the convention here on Stack Overflow is to upvote (click the up arrow next to the answer) and/or accept this answer (click the check mark). The latter also marks your question as resolved, so it no longer comes up as requiring attention.